# How to fetch Event, Birthdate, Friendlist, Event From the Facebook for iPhone using Webservices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

I want to know how to fetch the birthdate, event, and friendlist from the Facebook using JSON web service for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Facebook's [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) or even the deprecated [REST API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/).

Of course, it I would strongly recommend using the Graph API not just because the REST API is deprecated but because its pretty sweet.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this You can use ShareKit.It's the best and easy way to achieve this. check how to use it [here](http://getsharekit.com/docs/)